# Cron Jobs not successful 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: magento-enterprise, cron, nginx, extensions

I am having an issue where i can not run specific cron jobs successfully. Within the scheduler in magento. The job takes quite some time until i get "502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.4.4". I'm not 100% sure on how to proceed, i am suspecting it could be using too much memory...

Among others, one of the cron jobs i am trying to run is from an extension called Xtento  Advanced Order Status "orderstatusimport/observer::importOrderStatusJob".

Comment: Any errors in the webserver log?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party modules (Xtento)

Comment: Your cron should never be run via HTTP. It should be run by command line only.